# preview embedded URL laravel

Tags: laravel

in my livewire post show blade I did this if I create a post with a link the is not previewing in my show view page , I have tried to different URL still not working
https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed

```
public function mount (Post $post)
{
     $this->post = $post;
   
    preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $post->body, $matches);
    $this->urlDetails = collect($matches[0])->map(function ($url) {
       $embed = new Embed();
       $info = $embed->get($url);
        return ['info' => $info, 'title' => $info->title];  
    })->all();
}
```

getting the URL like this in my show blade view

```
{{ $urlDetails['title'] ?? '' }}
```

Comment: You will want to modify the registration create page, add a integer field that is foregin related called `refferer_id` and add the refferers id on registration. https://medium.com/zestgeek/customize-laravel-registration-form-with-additional-fields-de2c1e294a37

Comment: how can the user be tracked , let's say I would like to get the name of the user that referred me